# Android code : When clicked on an image a toast should SHOW by its IMAGE NAME.?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio-2.1, cardview

I have created a card view. Now i want to show A TOAST message with the image name that is clicked. Please help...

MY JAVA CODE(fragment) WHICH IMAGES ARE ADDED..

```
public void prepareAlbums(){
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2,
                R.drawable.album3,
                R.drawable.album4,
                R.drawable.album5,
                R.drawable.album6,
                R.drawable.album7,
                R.drawable.album8,
                R.drawable.album9,
                R.drawable.album10,
                R.drawable.album11};
        int j=0;

        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){


            Album  a=new Album("Song"+i,i,covers[j]);
            j++;
            albumList.add(a);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

MY XML CODE ..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="clikii"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_margin_top"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY CODE WHERE I USED MY ONCLICK METHOD...

```
public void clikii(View view){
        TextView as=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        String qq=as.getText().toString();


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,qq, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs13W.jpg)

When i use this code only first image_title is shown for all images..

i want to get name from image and show it in TOAST message .. Anyone Please Help..

Comment: Can you share the code of setting the click listener?

Comment: @Shaishav  in the xml:  android:onClick="clikii"

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try This   
   public void clikii(View view){
    TextView as=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
             as.setText("yourImageNAme");
    String qq=as.getText().toString();


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,qq, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

Comment: Not Working ... First image name is showing for all All IMAGES .. :(

Comment: getall the image name in array list and get corresponding image name with help of click postion and set to text view and toast

Comment: I have Allready set all images in an ARRAY called covers(As shown in  the  code) .. How to use the click position code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public void clikii(View view){
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view;
        TextView as = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.title);
        String qq = as.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, qq, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: also need to set 'clickii' on the RelativeLayout not the ImageView

Comment: But it is only working when clicked on the text view.. Clicking on image not working'

Comment: @Jithin set it in the <RelativeLayout>...WHERE you want the click to happen

Comment: I have allready set it inside the relative layout where my image and textview is Present

Comment: @Jithin Well, it should work. Have you put `android:clickable="true"` on `<RelativeLayout>`?

Comment: @Jithin yeah..since we want it to 'consume' the event instead of passing it to its children.

Comment: I done that. Still not working on image. I have done clickable=true on inmage view. is that the problem .?

Comment: @Jithin Nah..that should be ok...try setting `android:onClick` on the CardView...otherwise I'm not sure whats wrong.